# Publish Specific Version of Page

Tags: 2011, publishing

Suppose I have 10 versions of a page. Is it possible to publish specific versions like version 5 or version 7 from tridion? I am trying to look for an option which would provide me a capability to publish different versions to different targets.I am using tridion 2011 sp1. If it is possible what are the necessary  options available to achieve this.

Comment: How would versions of the page be related to each other and what's in common in delivery that they're still the same page?

Answer (score 5):

for Publishing specific version, just right click page->versioning -> history,

then right click on the required version and rollback, then select

> Create a new version that is a copy of version 7 (no versions are
>   deleted).

after that version rolled-back, just published that.

Comment: Perhaps not the cleanest solution, but I do think that is the only way indeed. The Publisher will automatically publish the current version (that is the last checked in version, with an exception for Workflow). So a "rollforward" and a Publish will do the trick, after the publish you can "rollback" again if desired. But keep in mind that the Content Delivery system does not care about versions, it will show what is last published, period.

Comment: I am trying to look for an option which would provide me a capability to publish different versions to different targets.

Comment: I can see Bart's suggestion combined with some automation from the Event System doing the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you are coming from the Sitecore background where we create different item versions for different target/languages etc, here in SDL cleanest solution would be to use separate publications for different targets and update the page/component accordingly in local publication.

Comment: +1: Leverage Blueprinting for what it was designed for. Different versions for different targets sounds like a perfect match for Blueprinting

Answer (score 4):

You are probably more concerned about the Component versions used on the page than the page itself.  The trick with version rollback (from Raj) also works there, and doing this one time is probably OK but more often would be a headache.

If you do this a lot you probably would be better off making a Custom Page that uses the Tridion APIs to provide a more business oriented app.  Tridion has all the info and features to make this happen - but the 'flow' of your use case doesn't have a friendly step-by-step GUI behind it.  This use case comes up every now and then, but I think it's an edge case.

Comment: Rolling back the page doesn't roll back the components to go back to the same situation that was there when the previous version of page was active.